# Dongles stop connecting in Ubuntu after switching to Windows

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, usb, bluetooth, dongle

Every time I install Ubuntu, my dongles (Wi-Fi / Bluetooth) stop connecting in Windows until I change them to a different USB port, however when I do that they stop working in Ubuntu and I have to plug them in to a different USB port again. This happens every time I switch the operating system that I boot to in the dual boot from Windows to Ubuntu or from Ubuntu to Windows.

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that each operating system is assigning a different USB port to your dongles. When you switch between Windows and Ubuntu, the USB port assignments change causing the dongles to be unrecognized or incorrectly initialized.

To solve this problem try connecting the dongles consistently in the same USB port each time that you boot to a different operating system. That means you have to use a different USB port to connect the dongle in Windows than you do in Ubuntu and you have to use that port consistently every time that you connect the dongle to that OS.